# Dockerfile that is used for building spring-cloud-dataflow-server image

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have downloaded the Spring cloud Dataflow server code from GitHub at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow. I am trying to understand how the docker image is build for this server. But I am unable to find dockerfile in this codebase.

Reference documentation section "Adding a Custom JDBC Driver" calls for modifying Pom.xml and rebuild with very little information. I need to use a custom jar and rebuild the image.

Already looked into this post https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2489 but I am trying to understand how the orginal image for Spring Dataflow server is built.

Answer (score 3):

The Maven configuration to build the Spring Cloud Data Flow server is [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/pom.xml#L118)

To build the docker image, you can run the following from your cloned repo (assuming you are on the latest):

```
./mvnw clean install -DskipTests
./mvnw docker:build -pl spring-cloud-dataflow-server
```

Comment: While the answer is correct, it's a lot of of work to get a Dockerfile as the fabric8 plugin needs Docker also to be running. The Dockerfile could be included at least as a template in the documentation. The idea here is to be able to use a different base image and alternative build tools like skaffold which don't need a local docker setup.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Gopinathan. I have used the below dockerfile instead of changing the POM.xml and rebuilding the docker image.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/java/jdk:8u212-zulu-alpine as build
RUN apk add --update \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

WORKDIR /workspace/app

RUN mkdir target

RUN curl -sS -o /workspace/app/target/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar

RUN curl -sS -o /workspace/app/target/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.16/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar

RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar)

RUN cp /workspace/app/target/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar /workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib/  

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/java/jdk:8u212-zulu-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/target/dependency
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app

RUN echo "$(ls -lR /app)"

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.single.DataFlowServerApplication"]
```

Answer (score 0):

dockerfile-from-image would help to reverse engineer from docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Upvoted Ilyaperumal Gopinathan's answer, the best way is to build the project. The fabric8 maven docker plugin requires docker to be installed locally however - surely a lot of work to get to the 4 lines below.

This is the image produced by the 2.7.1 build -

```
FROM springcloud/baseimage:1.0.0
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
COPY maven /
VOLUME ["/tmp"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/maven/spring-cloud-dataflow-server.jar"]
```

The spring cloud base image seems to be simply an Ubuntu base with Java 8 installed (https://github.com/spring-cloud/baseimage)?