# CORS Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

How to enable CORS in spring cloud dataflow to make it api accessible from external web app like angular?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cross Origin Resource Sharing is not supported out of the box in SCDF.
But, Spring Cloud Data Flow server application is a `Spring Boot` app and can be customized and extended.

You could add global CORS configuration to SCDF custom application. For information on how to do this, you can refer to [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-cors).

You can also check the sample [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/custom-dataflow-builds/dataflow-server-25x) on how to customize SCDF server application.

Comment: Thank you. Will take a look.

Comment: I am thinking of trying SCDF server behind Zuul proxy. Hope it should work too? In that case where should I set this property if SCDF is running on Kubernetes  "server.use-forward-headers"

Comment: where can find details to rebuild the SCDF docker image for kubernetes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879764/dockerfile-that-is-used-for-building-spring-cloud-dataflow-server-image/56884430#56884430

Comment: Thank you your suggestion worked to by customizing SCDF server for CORS and publishing it as docker image on kubernetes. The part where it fails is CORS and access related to websocket (e.g grafana, task graph etc..), what would be the approach to overcome it? Thanks

Comment: It worked as expected setting up scdf behind Cloud Gateway without customizing it.